# Use a MySQL user variable as table_name in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables in my MYSQL v5.7.9 database:

**world1:**
 `player_id | city_id | wood_max_level | wheat_max_level | gold_max_level | meat_max_level`

**world2:**
 `player_id | city_id | wood_max_level | wheat_max_level | gold_max_level | meat_max_level`

**upgrading:** `world | player_id | city_id | building | level`

Inside **upgrading**:
`building` contains a string: 'wood_max_level', 'wheat_max_level', 'gold_max_level' or 'meat_max_level'
`world` also contains a string: 'world1' or 'world2'.

What I'm trying to do is select `building` and `level` from upgrading.

Then I would like to update `world1` or `world2` depending on what `world` contains and set the `level` to the column name contained in building.

**Here's an example**

I have a row inside `upgrading` that look's like that:

```
  world   | player_id | city_id |     building    | level
 'world1' |    190    |     1   | 'wood_max_level'|   2
```

after executing the query I would have the table `world1` affected because it was set inside `upgrading` as column `world`. `world1` would be like so:

```
player_id | city_id | wood_max_level | wheat_max_level | gold_max_level | meat_max_level
   190    |    1    |        2       |        0        |        0       |       0
```

I already have a working 'PHP version' of this. Basically I do a first query then return an array and foreach element I do an other query.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT 
  @world := world,
  @building := building,
  @level := level FROM upgrading;
UPDATE @world
  SET @building = @level;
```

Above I have defined three user variables (their value is taken from the table `upgrading`. In the 2nd statement I'm trying to UPDATE the world contained in @world (either `world1` or `world2`). In the example above it would look like so: @world = 'world1', @building = 'wood_max_level', @level = 2

The last line isn't correct because @world is a string. I can I make I work?

Comment: `sql` is not enough! Please tag with the acutal DBMS (vendor and version)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help your explanation.

Comment: In oracle we use [merge](http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html) for that. In [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) and [tsql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) we use CTE expressions.

So what's your dialect?

Comment: I have added it: MySQL v5.7.9 on WAMP

Comment: Subquery. UPDATE your_table SET var=(SELECT var2 from another_table WHERE ....) WHERE.....

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added an example

Comment: please consider adding a comment if you thing this question can be improved

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, since your table structures are different, you would probably need to do a Pivot/unpivot. Alternatively you can use case statements like so;

```
UPDATE world
SET 
    world.wood_max_level = case when upgrading.building = 'wood_max_level' THEN world.wood_max_level + 1 else world.wood_max_level end,
    ... similar for other levels ...
FROM upgrading
INNER JOIN world1 
    on upgrading.world = world.world_id
WHERE completion_time > 0;
```

---

After editing your question it appears you also will also need to use Dynamic Sql, as you do not know the name of the table you wish to update until runtime... this is possible but is more advanced, and judging from the schema of your tables I suggest you read up on the basics of relational databases and try to rethink your schema so that this is not necessary, before creating complicated queries. A hint would be to have a WorldId column in a single world table, which would eliminate the need to have two different tables with the same schema (usually a sign your design is wrong). I would seriously read-up on database design before trying to build a game around this as it will be much more difficult to change your database design later on in the process than it will now...

Comment: `world` isn't a table it's a column from `upgrading`

Comment: still have `UPDATE world` on line 1

Comment: so your table is called world1? You know what i meant surely... I was providing pseudo-code because from the table schemas you provided, there isn't even a link between the two tables (world_id or such) so I cant test a proper query until you post your actual table definitions. Or if you have - this wont work as your schemas are wrong...

Comment: `player_id` and `city_id` are the two links

Comment: Player id is a number in one table, and a string in the other... I would read up a bit on basics of databases before you undertake something like building a game...

Comment: sorry my mistake, it's indeed a integer on both tables. I got it wrong while writing the post

Comment: added an edit. I would seriously consider re-thinking your database schema before going further with development

Comment: Oh, that's good you tell me that, I though it was better to have `world1`, `world2`, ..., `worldn` instead of `world`. I was about to do the same with upgrading and split it up for each world. This thing is just a holiday project, alone I didn't really have the time to design everything...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what  you are looking for, and I am sure there is a much more elegant way to structure this, but I figured this would at least give you a starting point example to look at.

I start by declaring my variables, followed retrieving the information I will need to perform the updates into a temp table. I pull out the individual values I want from that table to form variables I can use in the dynamic sql query. I define my query, and execute using sp_executesql, then drop my temp table to clean up. You can, of course throw all this into a procedure. Here is the code:

```
declare @TargetTable varchar(50);
declare @TargetColumn varchar(50);
declare @ValueToUpdate int;

select 
    World, Player_Id, Building, [Level]
into 
    #Upgrades
from 
    dbo.Upgrading
where 
    Player_Id = 2;

set @TargetTable = (
    select World 
    from #Upgrades
    );
set @TargetColumn = (
    select Building 
    from #Upgrades
    );
set @ValueToUpdate = (
    select [Level] 
    from #Upgrades
    );

declare @Query nvarchar(max);
set @Query = 'update dbo.'+@TargetTable+' set '+@TargetColumn+'='+convert(nvarchar,@ValueToUpdate)+' where Player_Id = 2';

exec sp_executesql @Query;

drop table #Upgrades;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but it isn't ideal. I wanted to only execute one query and I ended up using more. Also it's more PHP than SQL...

```
public function checkOnBuildingQueue()
{
    // SQL query and prepare the request
    $sql = 'SELECT world, player_id, city_id, building, level FROM upgrading WHERE completion_time < :time;
            DELETE FROM upgrading WHERE completion_time < :time;';
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    // prepare statements and execute query
    $params = array(
        'time' => time() + 2
    );
    $query->execute($params);

    // return selected rows in array
    $upgrades = $query->fetchAll();
    unset($sql, $params, $query);

    // $upgrade contains all finished upgrades
    foreach($upgrades as $upgrade)
    {
        $world = $upgrade['world'];
        $player_id = $upgrade['player_id'];
        $city_id = $upgrade['city_id'];
        $building = $upgrade['building'] . '_level';
        $level = $upgrade['level'];

        $sql = 'UPDATE '.$world.' SET '.$building.' = '.$level.' WHERE player_id = '.$player_id.' AND city_id = '.$city_id.'';
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    }

}
```